# Не работает форма ajax в laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, mvc

При нажатии на кнопку формы выдает ошибку.

Сама ошибка: Controller method not found.

Вот код:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#form").submit(function() {
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/send",
   data: $(this).serialize()
  }).done(function() {
   $(this).find("input").val("");
   alert("Спасибо за заявку! Скоро мы с вами свяжемся.");
   $("#form").trigger("reset");
  });

 });
 
});
</script>
```

```html
Форма:

<form id="form" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" required /><br />
  <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон" required /><br />
  <button>Отправить</button>
 </form>
  
  Роут:
  
  Route::post('/send', 'AjaxController@send');
  
  Контроллер:

  <?php
 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 
class AjaxController extends Controller
{
public function send(Request $request)
{
   echo 'lol';
}
}
```

Comment: попробуй сделать `composer dump-autoload` или `php artisan clear-compiled`

Answer (score 0):

укажи правильный `url` с расширением-форматом на конце (`send.php` `send.html` ...) в зависимости какой у тебя

Comment: Объясните, почему это имеет значение и как именно это поможет решить проблему?

Comment: @andreymal мне кажется он просто не может найти запрашиваемый `url`

Answer (score 0):

```
    var token  = $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content');
    $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token }});
```

С токеном может проблема? Вставь эти строки в js перед ajax.

А это в шаблон:

```
    <meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
```

Или отключи проверку токена, но как без компа не подскажу